# Change disk reader name

Tags: hard-drive

I have three disks on my computer:

- The one containing my Windows system, whose name is 'Samsung SSD...'
- The one containing my Debian system, whose name is 'WDC...'
- The one containing most of my other programs, whose name is 'WDC...'

As you can see, when I want to change the boot order, it is hard to know which one contains the Debian system. How can I change the names of these disks?

[image: These are the names I have]

Comment: Not a direct answer, but FYI:
The `EZEX` is the 3.5'' WD Blue drive whilst the `SPZX` is the 2.5'' WD Blue.

Answer (score -1):

You can't change the names of the disks, as they are really model numbers.

To achieve what you want you need to run `diskmgmt.msc`=Disk Management and find drive that has NTFS partitions - this is the one with other programs, and other one is the Debian disk - should have partition marked as `RAW`.